# Use same actionresultmethod for multiple viewmodels?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have three viewmodels to edit the same domain object.
I use AutoMapper to map to viewmodels from the domain object.

GET

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("administrators"))
{
    viewName = "EditAdmin";
    editOrder = Mapper.Map<Order, ViewModels.Order.Admin_ViewModel>(order);
}
else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("administrators"))
{
    viewName = "EditTechnician";
    editOrder = Mapper.Map<Order, ViewModels.Order.Technician_ViewModel>(order);
}
else if (Roles.IsUserInRole("clients"))
{
    viewName = "EditClient";
    editOrder = Mapper.Map<Order, ViewModels.Order.Client_ViewModel>(order);
}

RedirectToRoute(viewName, editOrder);
```

POST
Is it possible to use the same method for all viewmodels?
Possibly by letting the ViewModels inherit from "ViewModelbase"?
Tried this with no success :(

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT:
This is what my method looks like now:

```
public ActionResult EditAdmin(ViewModels.Order.Admin_ViewModel model) {...}
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
I wasn't able to understand how to use composition (tried it for a few hours). So I went with this to clean up a bit. These are the handlers for my three viewmodels:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "administrators")]
public ActionResult EditAdmin(Admin_ViewModel model)
{
    return SaveViewModel(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "technicians")]
public ActionResult EditTechnician(Technician_ViewModel model)
{
    return SaveViewModel(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "clients")]
public ActionResult EditClient(Client_ViewModel model)
{
    return SaveViewModel(model);
}
```

SaveViewModel looks like this:

```
protected ActionResult SaveViewModel(dynamic model)
{ ... }
```

I don't feel to good about this solution. Could you please give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO - ViewModel should plain and simple. If you introduce inheritance, it is going get complicated.

I suggest you to use **composition** to build the ViewModel you want. So if the user is in a particular role, objects which are not related to the Role will be null when the page is posted. With that you can stick to one POST method rather than many.

**Update :** 
If you really want to have the inheritance in ViewModel. Custom model binder is the solution, if the default one is not working

Comment: @JimH Could you please share the three ViewModels, then I could give a try.